# Using an old version of N2CMS, how can I use .no instead of /no to change language?

Tags: url, hostname, n2cms

The project I am working with is using an old version (v.2.1.0.1) of N2CMS.

To start with, I want to avoid upgrading to the latest N2 version, not because I don't like new things (because I do) but because since I am using such an old version it would take a lot of efford trying to upgrade it and if there's a way to solve this issue in a more time efficient way then I need to do that instead.

What I need to do is to enable the url to set the languageroot for the website and having it not only rely on the /lang. For example, i want my website.se to point towards /sv and my website.no to point towards /no. Right now .se is default so no matter the URL, swedish is the language shown. The twist is, and the reason for why I need it done this way, that I am loading data from another database and showing it on the site, list of categories and products (/keyrings for example). These things don't have the /sv or /no in the url. The result here is that even if I get /no to working along side the .no url, as soon as I click on an item in that list without the language code in the url then I will automatically be redirected to the default swedish languageroot. So I want to completely rely the N2CMS languageroot on the URL and not the /lang. I know that this is possible in the later versions of N2CMS but I am hoping there's a workaround in the older versions as well.

In this version I have a startpage and under the startpage i have languageroots. Each language root has the option to enter an URI Name, in my case i have swedish and norwegian so that's /sv and /no. An example from the site could look like this: /sv/om-oss, the norwegian way would be /no/om-oss. 
In the later versions (that I use for other and newer projects) I have just the startpage and in its settings I am able to enter the hostname, this is what I want for my site (not necessarily have it changable in N2CMS, it's easier to just have it coded in).

Does anyone have any experience in this, or knowledge deeper than mine when it comes to these sort of things?

Answer (score 0):

Just for record, this problem got solved http://n2cms.codeplex.com/discussions/397494